# menu appearing outside the screen border

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `navBar` menu. when clicked opens a submenu.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navegacao">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      ...
    </ul>

    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <div class="p-2"><i class="material-icons">face</i></div>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">José da silva</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" id="menuUsuario" style="padding: 2rem">
          <app-menu-porteiro></app-menu-porteiro>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

css

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display:none;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  width: 300px;
}

#menuUsuario.dropdown-menu {
  width: 300px;
}

#menuUsuario.dropdown-menu:before {
   position: absolute;
   top: -7px;
   left: 4%;
   display: inline-block;
   border-right: 7px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 7px solid #ccc;
   border-left: 7px solid transparent;
   border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   content: '';
 }

#menuUsuario.dropdown-menu:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: 4%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}
```

As shown in the image below, the menu goes beyond the stipulated area of the layout. I would like it to be aligned to the right margin.

[image]

I want it to fit within the limit of the screen. But as I'm new to css I can not solve this problem.

Comment: Could you post all of your CSS? Or a link to your site? You're could use a `position: fixed` or `absolute` on `.dropdown-menu`. Then set the `top: 2em` (the height of your menu) and `right: 0`.

Comment: Try adding `dropdown-menu-right` class after `dropdown-menu`, more details [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#dropup-variation)

Comment: Use the Bootstrap classes when able to! I don't use it much, @Swellar, so I didn't recognize it.

Comment: @RafaelSilva I would recommend adding the relevant bootstrap tag.

Comment: not work dropdown-menu-right. the part posted above is any css relevant to the problem.